# How can I simulate the templating features of asp.net masterpages in html/javascript while keeping my site search engine friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm used to ASP.NET masterPages to help me maintain a consistent look and feel in an ASP.NET site without a lot of duplication. I'm trying to do more pure HTML/Javascript sites but find myself wanting to go back and use masterPages. I also don't want to ruin my chances of good ratings in search engines. How can I simulate the templating features of asp.net masterpages in html/javascript while keeping my site search engine friendly?

Note: I'd like to stick to just HTML/Javascript. No server-side solutions, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've landed on a great solution that doesn't require server tech: [Single Page Applications (SPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: This answer would be much better if it explained **why** this the best solution for your problem, rather than linking off-site.

Answer (score 0):

If php is a possibility:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'layout.html'; ?>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

A not as Elegant solution would be iFrame.

```
    <iframe src="layout.html"></iframe>
```

You might want to take a look at this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114458/Master-Pages-using-HTML-and-JavaScript

Comment: I'd like to stick with just plain ole HTML/Javascript. I'm already coming from a server-side tech... don't want to go back just right now.

Comment: I believe he is looking for something that can run without server code. So just html/js

Comment: That's what I thought, just threw out another Possibility :p

Comment: that certainly wont be search engine friendly since much of the header and footer won't be accessable to the crawler

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate stylesheets.  If I understand your statement "maintain a consistent look and feel", CSS is the easiest way to go!

Comment: MasterPages include much more than CSS... I'm looking for html structure, commonly referenced css and javascript files, the whole bit.